# jQuery .fadeIn() won't overwrite css

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, opacity

I'm trying to use jquery's fade in function to do as it does and it works fine if I use fadeOut before to change the opacity to 0 but if I set the opacity to 0 in the css the jquery function won't overwrite the css.

How would I get the function to work while keeping the element hidden before the click event?

Comment: show what you've tried.

Comment: instead of setting `opacity: 0` why don't you hide the element using `display: none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) has problem if the element is not hidden, So you can try [fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)

```
$('div').css('opacity', '0').fadeTo(2000, 1)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/F9aad/)

or try [animate({opacity: 1})](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) like

```
$('div').css('opacity', '0').animate({
    opacity: 1
}, 2500)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ny8p4/)